# intellij - maven project: Unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project ([repo](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/db-interface)) which I can properly compile with the *Maven Projects* widget in intellij. But, I cannot build using the Build menu, and there are a lot of false positives in the code highlights. It seems that intellij is not able to find certain maven dependencies, even though I "synchronize"d and "maven-reimport"ed:

[image: Screenshot]

How to fix these imports easily? (I recall the module compiling fine in other projects.)

Comment: It is unclear what I did, but after I used the *maven projects* widget to fully deploy the app (ie push to maven), these errors seem to have resolved.

Comment: there sometimes is a bit of a delay when intellij should recognize missing jar files it could resolve through maven. once maven downloads the files and stores them in the local repository intellij will load them as well - but not load them itself. what often helps is a "mvn dependency:go-offline" - this will download all dependencies and plugins for the project - and let intellij re-index. Usually the warnings then disappear for me.